# Insert file names into files using find and sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I have hundreds .htm files and i need to replace `<title>sometext</title>` with the actual file name.
For example:
i have file called `records-england.htm` and i need to replace `<title>sometext</title>` in this file with file name like so `<title>records-england.htm</title>`

Even better if without extension - but that does not matter.
I'v tried like this but it's not working:

```
find . -name *.htm | while read file; do sed "s|<title>sometext</title>|<title>$file</title>|g" {} \; done
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is the title always `sometext` or is it some arbitrary text?

Comment: `while read file` and `do sed ...` are two independent subprocesses. `$file` variable doesn't exist in the second one.

Comment: @legends2k, it's always the same text

Comment: Do you have `gnu awk 4.1` and can test my solution?

Comment: I have gnu awk 4.0.1 using Ubuntu 14.04 and it's not working

Comment: Ok, You need `4.1` as in Ubuntu 4.10 or you can update `gnu` manually.

Comment: @Jotne gawk 4.1 installed and it works now, but - not in subfolder(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`s FILENAME.  Needs to be `gnu awk` >= `4.1` due to  `-i inplace`

```
awk -i inplace '{a=FILENAME;sub(/\.htm$/,"",a);gsub(/<title>[^<]*<\/title>/,"<title>"a"</title>")}1' *.htm
```

This will change `<title>sometext</title>` (where  `sometext` can be anything) to `<title>filename(without extension)</title>`

Comment: It did not go to subfolders, but i moved all .htm files to current folder and your command works well. Thank You.

Comment: I was trying  to make it work also with subfolderd and it forks like this:
find -name "*.htm" -print -exec awk -i inplace '{a=FILENAME;sub(/\.htm$/,"",a);gsub(/<title>[^<]*<\/title>/,"<title>"a"</title>")}1' {} \;

Is it possible to remove path? Using like -F/ somewhere?
Actual result in file:
<title>./results/2014/19.10.2014 - pila</title>

Expected result in file:
<title>19.10.2014 - pila</title>

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem in your code, you can try this :

```
find -name "*.htm" | while read file; do sed "s|<title>sometext</title>|<title>${file##*/}</title>|g" -i $file; done
```

Sed need the -i option to specify which files you want to edit and I use a parameter expansion to only display the basename of the file.

Comment: option `g` not needed in this case (unless a bad formated html file). Assuming title are not with meta character. For this you can prepare an *escaped* version of file name in a previous instruction to use inside of your sed.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
's/\<title\>.*\<title\>/title>$file<title/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for any arbitrary title text. If you don't want it to be any text but some fixed text then change `<title>.*</title>` to `<title>sometext</title>`.

```
 find -type f -name '*.htm' -printf '%P\0%f\0' | xargs -0 -n2 sh -c 'fil="${2/\.htm/}"; sed -i -e "s;<title>.*</title>;<title>$fil</title>;" $1' replace
```

It transfers the result of `find` to `sh` using `xargs`; `bash` strips the extension off and give the arguments to `sed` which does the replacement.

**Arguments:**

To `find`

- `-type f` find files
- `-name '*.htm'` which has extension `htm`
- `printf '%P\0%f\0'` output full file path then a ASCII null, followed by just the filename (stripping the path) and again an ASCII nul

To `xargs`

- `-0` use ASCII nul as the delimiter
- `-n2` pick up at most 2 arguments from the list for each execution of the command

To `sh`

- `-c` reads commands from the first non-option argument
- a bash script which takes `$1` (file path) and `$2` (file name) as arguments; does regex replacement to snip the extension. Passing a dummy string `replace` for it to take `$0`

To `sed`

- `-i` in-place replace in file
- `-e` the script to execute

Comment: It works but i have a lot of subfolder and that also adds subfolder(s) name into <title> + file extension.
Is it possible to add file name to <title></title> without subfolder name and without extension?

Comment: assuming there is no meta character in file name nor `;` or `'`. To be secure, you need to prepare a bit the file name (variable content) before. Use the same sed but included in a batch with this precaution first.

Comment: Sorry, it's not working in subfolder.
sed: can't read 04.06.2000-basel.htm: No such file or directory
That exact htm file is in subfolder.

Comment: Not working for me:
`sed: can't read results/2010/18.07.2010: No such file or directory`
`sed: can't read -: No such file or directory`
`sed: can't read gavle.htm: No such file or directory.`

Path and filename is: results/2010/18.07.2010-gavle.htm

Comment: @Jaur Check the fixed answer now, it also removes the extension when replacing the title.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
outFile=/tmp/myOutFile.out
touch $outFile
while read line
do
    name=$line
    echo "<title>$name</title>" >> $outFile
done < $1
```

1. Create a new .sh (e.g. modifyFile.sh) file with the code above.
2. Grant it execute rights - chmod +x modifyFile.sh
3. Run it with the file which contains your file names or w/e - ./modifyFile.sh myInputFile.txt
4. You will get results in /tmp/myOutFile.out